# Should my React component handle mouse clicks and touches different

Tags: reactjs, web

I have a react component that is supposed to act like react native touchable opacity component.  Right now it works great, but only on touchscreen.  Should I also make it work for mouse down/up events as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more interactivity, probably you can make us of `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` event. or else you can simply use css `:hover` to add style to the element